# Kali Linux(Live Version): Linux resets after restarting Live version?

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

A few hours ago I mounted a legitimate Kali Linux (x64) on a USB 3.0 32GB drive.

When I boot a PC from a USB device and select the Kali Linux USB drive, I select the 'Live (amd64)' option.

I automatically log in to the Root account, I made another personal Admin account and logged into that account. I did some stuff there and browsed some sites.

After +/- 30 minutes I shut the PC down and a few hours later, now, I tried logging in to the created personal Admin account. But it didn't exist any more.

So my question is: Why is this happening and how do solve this issue? I want it to be a bootable Kali Linux drive and run it on various PC's.

PS I am a beginner to Linux, so this might be an extremely dumb question. In that case; my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of Live discs comes from the days of using a CD/DVD disc, so it is read-only, with any changes only made in RAM.

You may want to install Kali instead, on another disk partition or on a virtual machine.

Or, there may be another option you can choose other than 'Live (amd64)'.

Comment: You can perform a Live USB persistence. Which means that files are being saved etc. But therefore you need to create a new partition on the USB drive?

size=5gb
read bytes _ <  /mnt/my_usb/persistence.conf
umount /dev/sdb3

The second line isn't recognised. I replaced my_usb for the name of my USB but still it is not being recognised.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well the problem, it is because you didn't allocate a memory space for your session (kind of).
You should solve it by following this video's steps:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oojtAm_v6jc

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1126578)